# How do i resize my array from camera to fit model for face recognition?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, face-recognition

Okay so long story short i made a model for face recognition. Now when i want to predict from my model i get the following error:

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_3_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (182, 182, 3)

im using my camera and face detection works and draws a rectangle, its just that my face recognition prediction gives error.

I'm new to machine learning and im really catching myself where things need to go so dont judge me on begginer my mistakes :/

I have tried some solutions that worked for some people like reshape etc. but it didnt for me.

EDIT:
Okay so far you guys managed to help me to get rid of array error, but with resizing my roi_color i recieve new error:
 OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3363: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !dsize.empty() in function 'cv::hal::resize'

Thanks for your help,
Jan

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import random as rd
from pathlib import Path
import string
from keras.models import model_from_json


def Recog_face(x, y, roi_color, frame, recognizer_face):
    predictions = recognizer_face.predict(roi_color)
    color = (255, 255, 255) 
    stroke = 2   
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX 
    return cv2.putText(frame, predictions, (x,y), font, 1, color, stroke, cv2.LINE_AA)

def Detect_face(x, y, frame):
    color = (255, 0, 0)
    stroke = 1 
    end_cord_x = x + w 
    end_cord_y = y + h 
    return cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (end_cord_x, end_cord_y), color, stroke) 

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')




recognizer_face = model_from_json(open("face_rec.json", "r").read()) 


recognizer_face.load_weights('face_rec.h5')



cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, 
                                         minNeighbors=5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces: 

        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w] 
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        Detect_face(x, y, frame)

        # Face recognizer
        Recog_face(x, y, roi_color, frame, recognizer_face)





    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break 

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

classifier = Sequential()

# Convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu')) 
# Maxpooling To reduce the number of nodes will get in flattening step
# Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))) 
# adding second Convolution layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))) 
# Flatten
classifier.add(Flatten())
# Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu')) # 128 hidden nodes in the hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 5, activation = 'softmax')) # softmax function cause multiple outcome 
# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(classifier.summary()) 



from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, 
                                  shear_range=0.2, 
                                  zoom_range=0.2,
                                  horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('images/Training_set',
                                                target_size=(64, 64), 
                                                batch_size=32,
                                                color_mode='rgb',
                                                class_mode='categorical') 

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('images/Test_set',
                                            target_size=(64, 64),
                                            batch_size=32,
                                            color_mode='rgb',
                                            class_mode='categorical') 
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                        steps_per_epoch=380,
                        epochs=2,
                        validation_data= test_set,
                        validation_steps=127)


fer_json = classifier.to_json()
with open("face_rec.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(fer_json)
classifier.save_weights("face_rec.h5")
```

Comment: You're missing the batch dimension, try `Recog_face(x, y, roi_color[None], frame, recognizer_face)`

Comment: Now the output error is: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_3_input to have shape (64, 64, 3) but got array with shape (182, 182, 3)

Comment: So your input image has to be of that shape, `roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w][None]; roi_color = cv2.resize(roi_color, (64, 64))`

Comment: Definitely getting somewhere. but: roi_color = cv2.resize(roi_color, (64, 64)) outputs: 
error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3363: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !dsize.empty() in function 'cv::hal::resize'